# Как вывести точные степени на Python?

Tags: python

С помощью приведенного кода можно вывести все точные степени (не превосходящие данного числа), но только с конкретным показателем, введённым пользователем. А как вывести все точные степени вообще? Допустим, я хочу вывести все точные степени, не превосходящие числа 310610407. Как это сделать?

```
pow=int(input())
k=int(input())
i=1
while i**pow<=k:
    print(i**pow)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Код следует прилагать текстом.

Comment: В смысле любое число в любой степени и чтобы это не превосходило заданное число? Ну сделайте цикл в цикле. Только очень много подходящих чисел получится.

Comment: @CrazyElf, сделать цикл в цикле мне мешает то, что степени будут выведены беспорядочно. Например, если выводить сначала квадраты, а потом кубы, что число 8 будет выведено после 9. Ну а уж единица, так та вообще будет выведена более одного раза.

Comment: любое число в нулевой степени, ноль и единица в любой степени куда по условиям задачи вашей девать?

Comment: @xmikex, а ноль в нулевой степени — сколько?

Comment: просто выведи все числа до предела, ведь это будет степень 1 числа.

Comment: Ян Альбертович Дененберг,  питон вроде 1 выдаёт для этого выражения, но математически это NaN.

Comment: @xmikex, да Питон-то не выдаёт, только это ничего не меняет. Если каждое число в нулевой степени равно единице, а ноль в любой степени равен нулю, то непонятно, чему равен ноль в нулевой степени. Он же не может быть одновременно равен и нулю, и единице.

Comment: вообще получается вам нужно каждое число проверять - является ли оно какой-то степенью числа? Вычисляйте логарифмы числа по основанию от 2 до i, где i - квадратный корень числа и если логарифм будет целое число - выводите это число.

Comment: ноль в нулевой степени по стандарту математическому - это NaN. В питон будет единицу выводить.

Comment: Я попробовал цикл в цикле и всё перебрать, складывал числа в множество. На середине перебора память в Google Colab кончилась )))))   Так что чисел на выходе будет ОЧЕНЬ много. Зачем вам столько, куда вы их девать будете?

Comment: @CrazyElf Вообще хороша  задача. Код не хотите показать? Здесь же еще алгоритм важен

Comment: А, стоп, ведь все числа в степени 1 равны себе и попадут в список, получается, все числа от 1 до `n` попадут в итоговый список ))  Надо хотя бы от 2 тогда циклы делать, сейчас попробую...

Comment: @CrazyElf, я уже сделал, внизу, в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Чисто теоретически, точными степенями, не превосходящими N, будут все числа от 1 до N. Т.к. любое число есть первая степень самого себя. )))

Но если практически, исключить 0 и 1, то все сведется к факторизации всех чисел от 1 до N.

Опишу только алгоритм, кодить лень. )

Нужно наколдовать по принципу решета Эратосфена.

- создадим вектор из N чисел
- получим все простые числа 1 до N и вычеркнем их из вектора
- факторизируем все оставшиеся, получаем p1^q1 * p2^q2 * ... * pn^qn и оставляем только те, у которых q1=q2=...=qn > 1.
- ВСЕ

Решение с вектором не сжирает много памяти. Факторизация позволит гибко выбирать по довольно изощренным условиям.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется работает:

```
k=int(input())
d=0
while 2**(d+1)<=k:
    d+=1
list=[]
for pow in range (2, d+1):
    i=1
    while i**pow<=k:
        list.append(i**pow)
        i+=1
print(sorted(set(list)))
```

---

PS Внемлю конструктивной критике.

Comment: Извините, а вам был бы интересен ответ с прологом: _Кажется работает_? Пожалуйста, давайте ответ, когда решение проверено и вы в нём увверены.

Comment: Добавляйте элементы сразу в множество, так вы память сэкономите. Зачем раздувать список дублями?

Comment: @0xdb, полагаю, мне ответ с подобным прологом был бы даже очень интересен. Я бы протестировал программу давшего этот ответ и доказал, что ему только кажется.

Comment: @ЯнАльбертовичДененберг Этот сайт работаает несколько по другому: вам кажется - вы спрашивате, вы уверены - тогда отвечаете. QA называется.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, наверное

```
import math

all_powers = []
number = int(input('Введите число: '))
for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number))+1):#второе число можно заменить на number, 
                                            #потому что все числа до number являются 
                                            #степенью себя же (n)^1 = n. Следовательно, все числа 
                                            #сами по себе будут включены в список итоговых
    for power in range(int(math.log(number, i))+1):
        new_power = i**power
        if new_power not in all_powers:
            all_powers.append(new_power)

print(all_powers)
```

Comment: простите, только сейчас увидел Ваш ответ. Спасибо, но у меня вышло чуть чуть иначе, сейчас опубликую код.

Comment: `10` -> `[1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 9]`. Очень странный ответ.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy почему же?

Comment: Для некоторых оснований их первые степени включены в ответ, для некоторых не включены. В ответе есть `2` (`=2^1`), но нет `5` (`=5^1`).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да, все верно. сейчас поправлю ответ. спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Простой перебор в `Google Colab` считается минут 6:

```
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

n = 310610407
powers = set()
for i in tqdm(range(2, n+1)):
    for j in range(2, n+1):
        x = i ** j
        if x > n:
            break
        else:
            powers.add(x)

print(len(powers))
print(sorted(list(powers)))
```

Вывод:

```
100% 310610406/310610406 [05:43<00:00, 897346.56it/s]
18334
[4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, 36, 49, 64, 81, ...
```

P.S. Ой, что-то при перезапуске у меня уже другое кол-во получилось, что-то Google Colab мудрит и оптимизирует странным образом. Надо ещё перепроверять...

Comment: а что такое tqdm?

Comment: @xmikex Это библиотека, которая показывает прогресс, очень удобно, чтобы наглядно видеть, сколько итераций цикла прошло и сколько осталось. Время прошедшее и сколько до конца она тоже показывает.

Comment: если изменить правую границу вот так `range(2, int(n**.5)+1)`, то считать будет гораздо быстрее)

Comment: @MaxU Попробую, но у меня такое впечатление, что если два одинаковых цикла вложенных, то Google Colab их как-то дико оптимизирует. Но я попробую )